# HTML- how to put the icon right after the text

Tags: html, icons

I have to put an arrow icon next to a span (in the right side of the text "Yourself"- the one in the span. For some reason ii is displayed under the text.

```
<fieldset style="display: inline">
                    <div class="ui-grid-a" style="display: inline">
                    <span class="text-light ui-block-a">Post as: </span>
                    <span class="link toggle-post ui-block-b">Yourself<span id="dropdownIcon"          class="ui-icon-dropdown"></span></span>
                    </div>


                        <ul class="ul-post ui-listview" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" style="width: 240%; display:none">
                            <li data-postas="0" class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child">Yourself</li>

                                <li style="background-color: #CCCCCC" class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">As your company</li>

                                    <li data-postas="1" value="8" id="Ninja" data-company="8" class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">Ninja</li>

                                    <li data-postas="1" value="12" id="Batman" data-  company="12" class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-last-child">Batman</li>



                        </ul>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try this ?

```
<li data-postas="0" class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-first-child">
    Yourself <i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>
</li>
```

Here i used icon font awesome, check here: [enter link description here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

**UPDATE:**

For the first try this (i removed span with icon)

```
<span class="link toggle-post ui-block-b">
   Yourself <i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>
</span>
```